# Get the *two* height values of an canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get the *two* height values of this canvas.

```
<canvas width="886" height="792" style="display: block; opacity: 0.5; width: 834px; height: 746px;"></canvas>
```

I know, that I can access the one in the style by using `canvas.style.height;` but how do I get the other one?

Please help. Kind regards.

Comment: `canvas.height`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the other height by simply accessing the canvas's height property:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var height = canvas.height;
console.log(height);
```